# Grails count length of string

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I got `params.user` return the list.

Ex:

```
params.user = 10 20
```

then I used

```
    params.user.each { id ->
    }
```

Then id has value:

```
id = 10, id = 20
```

When `params.user` only returns `10`, iterating over it I get `1` and `0`.
So my idea is count the `length()` of `params.user` and put the condition

```
if (params.user == 1){
//to do something
}
```

But when I used `params.user.length()`, it returns 2 and I need it return 1. Please help

Comment: Using `params.list('user')`, a list is returned, either `[10,20]` or `[10]` in your case.

Comment: Thanks bro, lol things need to learn :)

Answer (score 2):

When you want to use the reserved params map, you actually use a Map. Then of course, when you do params.myParams.length(), you will get the length of your String value.

But Grails provides tools to get data from the param map. For a list use:

```
List myList = params.list('user')
```

Grails provides other ways to grab other kind of data:

```
    def intValue = params.int('paramInt')
    def shortValue = params.short('paramShort')
    def byteValue = params.byte('paramByte')
    def longValue = params.long('paramLong')
    def doubleValue = params.double('paramDouble')
    def floatValue = params.float('paramFloat')
    def booleanValue = params.boolean('paramBoolean')
```

Last but not least, if you have complex data to bind, don't forget to use Command Objects ;)